# Get current culture info based on TimeZoneId in C# application

Tags: c#, timezone, cultureinfo

In my C# console (.NET Core) application, I am saving **user TimeZoneId (e.g. Bangladesh Standard Time)** into the database. Now based on this timezone ID I would like to get current culture info. More specifically I would like to have **2-letter ISO Name (e.g. BD, US, UK)**. I can use the below code to get current culture info to get my 2-letter ISO Name. But it always shows - **en**. The reason maybe I have set the language settings to English from the Contol Panel in my Windows 10. So I am not finding the expected output. This is why I would like to get the culture info based on TimeZoneId as it is saved into the database. The code I have used to get current culture:

```
CultureInfo ci = CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture;

Console.WriteLine("Default Language Info:");
Console.WriteLine("* Name: {0}", ci.Name);
Console.WriteLine("* Display Name: {0}", ci.DisplayName);
Console.WriteLine("* English Name: {0}", ci.EnglishName);

Console.WriteLine("* 2-letter ISO Name: {0}", ci.TwoLetterISOLanguageName);
Console.WriteLine("* 3-letter ISO Name: {0}", ci.ThreeLetterISOLanguageName);
```

Current output:

[image]

Can anyone give me a C# example to get my solution?

Comment: This is fundamentally infeasible. What country would you expect to get from "Central European Standard Time" for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Time zone and culture/locale are orthogonal concepts.  They are completely disconnected.  One cannot tell the culture from the time zone or vice versa.

For example, I may be an English speaking American (culture code `en-US`), but I may be traveling or living in Japan (IANA time zone `Asia/Tokyo`, Windows time zone ID `Tokyo Standard Time`).

To be more specific in .NET:

```cs
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture    // how do you want your numbers and dates to be formatted?
CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture  // what language and dialect do you speak?
TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id         // what time zone are you observing? (on the local computer)
```